# Laravel - Composer Error while Installing Web Applications from GitHub using Composer Install

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Good day Laravel Professionals!

I downloaded an open-source web application from GitHub called Electronic Document Management System (EDMS) from this link: https://github.com/hpbyte/edms

I also tried following the step-by-step procedure on how to setup and install downloaded Laravel Web Applications from GitHub. But unfortunately while running composer install in CMD @ Administrator. I get the following Error, Screenshot link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4zH8.png

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'edms.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `u
  sers` where `status` = 0)


  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'edms.users' doesn't exist
```

Any help would be appreciated since I really need this EDMS for my tons of Documents. Thank you guys! Hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: Have you connected `DB`?

Comment: Looks like tables are missing, did you run (`php artisan migrate:install` and) `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: @kerbh0lz I did and it outputs the same error.

Comment: @Rob yes in .env file.

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=edms
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: @AbegailGraceUlanday Yeah, go to `edms` database using `phpMyAdmin` or `Adminer` and check if `users` table exist?

Comment: Please share more details. Also, please explain how this error message is related to Composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue about this: https://github.com/hpbyte/edms/issues/1
Basically you have to go to the AppServiceProvider File and comment some queries out:

```
$numReq = count(User::where('status',false)->get());
View::share('requests',$numReq);
$trash = count(Document::where('isExpire',2)->get());
View::share('trashfull',$trash);
```

Not the beste practice to have queries built in like that. You have no other choice than commenting that part out and undo that after composer install.

Comment: Should I unzip the files again, then comment some queries out then run composer install again?

Comment: Not quite sure how composer stopped.  Deleting the vendor folder in your document root, if existing, should be enough.

Comment: I managed to make it work thru the login page and signing in. But when I've redirected to the home page. I've been bombarded with errors such as.

(1/4) ErrorException
Undefined variable: trashfull                       


(2/4) ErrorException
Undefined variable: trashfull (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\edms-master\resources\views\inc\navbar.blade.php)

Comment: (3/4) ErrorException
Undefined variable: trashfull (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\edms-master\resources\views\inc\navbar.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\edms-master\resources\views\inc\navbar.blade.php)                                        and                                
(4/4) ErrorException
Undefined variable: trashfull (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\edms-master\resources\views\inc\navbar.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\edms-master\resources\views\inc\navbar.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\edms-master\resources\views\inc\navbar.blade.php)

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Oh wait I forgot to undo. Brb

Comment: Probably need to comment out everything again, run php artisan migrate and undo the commenting out of the code in the AppServiceProvider.

Comment: Oh wait. Why I'm having error called (1/1) HttpException, Any idea? This non-stop.

Comment: it Says, (1/1) HttpException in Application.php (line 926)

Comment: Have you copied the .env.example to .env and entered your database information there? Also don't forget to run php artisan key:generate.

Comment: Yes I did. But it kepts on giving me HTTPException error. I don't know why, Have you already encountered this problem? Since you already know that theres an issue about this.

Comment: No, the app is working for me. I did:
- git clone
- comment out stuff in ServiceProvider
- composer install 
- set .env + key:generate
- php artisan migrate
- undo comment out
- php artisan db:seed (to fill databse with dummy data)
I'm running an ubuntu based system.

Comment: So sad. Do you this works with Windows? I'm using WIndows 10.

Comment: This could be about the php version aswell, since the project is based on laravel v5.4.30

Comment: Then what's the best thing to do? Any idea? I badly need this one.

Comment: I can't imagine this being worth the effort. But if I really needed this to run I would install php 5.6 + an old version of npm/yarn. If that doesn't work you could try to run this on a docker container with php5.x. Imho you ran into a dead end.